# How to preserve app settings from a referenced assembly?

Tags: c#

I have an app `MainApp` that references another project `MyDLL.dll`.  Inside the MyDLL project I have made some user settings in a `Settings.settings` file that may be changed at runtime.  So it appears that these settings get saved in the `app.config` file of `MyDLL`.  But the problem is, the main project is `MainApp`, and `MyDLL.dll.config` does not, so far as I can see, get copied to the `MainApp` output folder.  This is reflected in the fact that even though I save the settings in the code of `MyDLL`, the next time I run `MainApp` the settings have gone back to the default.

I must be missing something really obvious here.  There has to be a way for related assemblies to preserve their settings values.  But how?

Comment: @user978511 - `Settings.Default.Save()`.  But you're right to check.  ;)

Comment: No, I'm using a `Settings.settings` file.  Sorry, I should have made that clearer in the question - will edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you can add an `app.config` to a library project, it has no effect to do so. Configuration is linked to the application, not the library.

You need to create the settings and configuration in your application itself. You can do something like including the library's `app.config` if you really wanted to, but that would probably not do what you want, either. It's best to just handle your configuration in the application.

Why is this so? Because what's to say it's valid to have user settings for your library in the first place? A library should not be tied to any particular kind of application. What if you used it in a Windows Service or an ASP.NET application?

Comment: All right, fair points, but in my particular situation I think it is justifiable.  `MainApp` is a WinForms exe, and `MyDLL` is a forms library.  The settings I want to restore relate to the column widths of a certain grid defined in `MyDLL`; I want to save the user's preferences.  Since the code is in `MyDLL` it would make sense to do the saving there, too, and from `MyDLL` I have to access to the calling app's settings.  If necessary I could put a listener from `MainApp` to catch column resizings and save there... but I didn't really want to get into that...

Comment: I'm just sure what you mean by it being *justified*, but none of that changes the fact that .NET configuration (and, therefore, settings) doesn't work like you want it to. Application settings are for the application, not the library.